# android app: clear text color of Button

Tags: android, button, textcolor

In my layout file, I don't explicitly define the text color of my ButtonView, so at runtime it renders as the default color (which is black).

In response to user input, I will set the text color of my button to Red, using the `setTextColor()` method. Then in response to another user input, I will need to revert to the default color. What's the best way to achieve it? I am looking for a `clearTextColor()` method but didn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guaranty the default color can be black , as each OEM can customize android platform.

You can use ValueAnimator to set the text color and reset it to default color when required

Here is a sample code.

**Change the color**

```
    final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    final ValueAnimator colorAnimation2 = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), button.getCurrentTextColor(), Color.RED);

    colorAnimation2.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            button.setTextColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
    colorAnimation2.start();
```

**Reset to default color**

```
 colorAnimation2.reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset it by setting the color to black something like this:
text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK), or text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0))